# C - Splitting a string into an array of n substrings without a delimiter

Tags: c, arrays, string

Let's say we have this input string:

```
str[1024]="ABCDEFGHIJKL"
```

And would like this output array:

```
{"ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL"}
```

How is it possible to split every 3 characters in `str` into an array of substrings?

Here is my code, but it only prints the first 3 characters, without actually storing them in an array:

```
int main(){
    char str[MAX]="ABCDEFGHIJKL";
    int count=0, i=0;
    char sub[3];
    char arr[6][3]={};

    while (count<3){
        sub[i]=str[i+count];
        count++;
        printf("%c", sub[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `[3]` is too short to contain the nul character, that you need to create proper C strings & print them.

Comment: only if you need them nul terminated, that said

Comment: The first 3 characters are all you tell the program to copy. They are stored in `sub[]` but `arr[][]` remains unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go through the entire string and put each character in its proper place. Don't forget that the string "ABC" occupies four bytes.

As you go through the characters of the input string, which output string they go into looks like this:

> 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3

That's `i/3`. The pattern of which position in the output they go in looks like this:

> 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2

That's `i%3`. So if `i` is the position in the input string, the position in the output array is `[i/3][i%3]`. Thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 512

int main(){
    char str[MAX]="ABCDEFGHIJKL";
    int count=0, i=0;
    char sub[3];
    char arr[MAX/3][4]={};

    /* Go through the string putting each character in
       its proper place */
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
        arr[i/3][i%3] = str[i];

    /* Print the strings out */
    for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(str) / 3); ++i)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
}
```

> ABC
>   DEF
>   GHI
>   JKL